# Chrome handling of ctrl-click on links with target="blank" (not target="_blank")

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes a website will use target="blank" instead of target="_blank" (missing the underscore). When doing a ctrl-click on those kinds of links in Chrome, the browser will open the link in a new tab AND switch to that tab, instead of just opening that link in a new tab. Right-clicking on the link and selecting "open in new tab" still works as it should.

It becomes a problem if you need to open a large number of links. Is there any way to get ctrl-click to work as intended with these types of links?

**Edit**: Chrome version is 15.0.874.121m, which is the latest at the time of this writing. For an example of the problem, copy and paste below into an HTML file and open in Chrome. Ctrl-click the first link will open a new tab only, ctrl-click the second link will open a new tab and switch to it. I'm trying to avoid having it switch to the new tab in the case of the second link.

```
<a href = "http://www.google.com" target="_blank">target="_blank"</a><br><br>
<a href = "http://www.google.com" target="blank">target="blank"</a>
```

Comment: Please include the version of Google Chrome you are using. :)

Comment: This is with Chrome version 15.0.874.121m, which I believe is the most up to date available.

Comment: I was able to replicate this bug. I'll play around in Chrome and see if I can find a workaround or fix.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem be a way to fix this behavior. Fortunately, I have a workaround for you.

Using an extension such as [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) or [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), you can write a global CSS rule to help distinguish when you need to **right-click** instead of **CTRL+click**. Using CSS selectors you can write something like this:

```css
a[target="blank"]:after {
    content: " [right-click]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. By any chance, would there be a simple way to use a similar extension to change any target="blank" to target="_blank" ?

Comment: Not as simple (from the client side) as this work around, but you could use a **userscript** with the appropriate JavaScript to effectively replace all the `target="blank"`. JavaScript is out of my realm, so hopefully another user can contribute this solution.